# programming a client to send a HTTP request message to a server with a UDP connection in Java

Tags: java, udp, httprequest

I need a client to send a http request message to a server but I don't know how to do it in UDP, using http 1.1

It needs to have a specific word in the method field, a specific name in the url field and a specific integer in the version field.

So if I wanted to send a http request message that had "inform" in the method field, "host1" in the url field and 40000 in the version field, how could I do this?

This is what I have now but it doesn't use http, I don't know how to change it.

```
BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
        DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
        InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("THIS-PC"); 
        byte[] sendData = new byte[128]; 
        byte[] receiveData = new byte[128];
        System.out.println("Enter:");
        String request ="INFORM ";
        String sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
       // request.concat("/r/n");
        request.concat(sentence);
      //  request.concat("/r/n");
        sendData = sentence.getBytes(); 
        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 40075); 

        clientSocket.send(sendPacket); 
       System.out.println("Packet sent");
        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length); 

        clientSocket.receive(receivePacket); 
        System.out.println("Packet received");
        String reply = new String(receivePacket.getData()); 

           System.out.println("FROM SERVER:" + reply); 
           clientSocket.close();
```

Comment: Do you *really* want to send HTTP over UDP? Or do you just want to use HTTP the standard way (over TCP/IP)?

Comment: HTTP needs a reliable transport. UDP isn't a reliable transport. You can't use HTTP over UDP. You might be able to use something that looks a bit like HTTP over UDP. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Could you explain for what purpose you want to send HTTP over UDP? This sounds like a major headache to me, as your server would need to handle things like out-of-order packets, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement the IEEE RFC for HTTP protocol?  Or just a simulation over UDP?

HTTP is a text-transfer based protocol that runs over TCP/IP.
HTTP default port is 80 but you "can" run a Datagram service through that port.

Losing some particular and helpful ways of the TCP/IP, such as delivering guarantee, order and correct serialization. Do you really have to do that?

Even if done this, you will also need to write a "service" that listens on that port using UDP, all of web-servers works with TCP as this is default and specified in RFC.

Also, read this for more info about:

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html

Or if you just want a simple app that send and receive data through UDP there are several examples on how to do that on the web.

Sorry if none of this helps.

Answer (score 0):

(a) You would need an HTTP server that spoke UDP. Do you really have that?

(b) You would need to implement the HTTP protocol in this client code. I don't see any attempt to do that. All you're doing is sending lines read directly from the console. No HTTP at all.